# How to hide radio button based on status

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery

I have choice field called status, default is set to a value submitted. It has the following values.
Save
Submitted
Rejected
Approved

if save or submitted is selected the other two should be hidden.
I have tried the below code.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
//alert("load");
//Show/hide columns based on Choice Field Selection
 var status = $("input[name='ctl00$ctl38$g_affa1499_f8c3_4242_bbb3_57110a81fc84$ctl00$ctl05$ctl12$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$RadioButtons']:checked").val();
 alert(status);

if ($("select[title='Submitted']").val() != "Yes" || $("select[title='Submitted']").val() != '' )
{
alert("submitted");
$("select[title='Submitted']").hide();
$("select[title='Rejected']").style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementByTitle('ctl00_ctl38_g_affa1499_f8c3_4242_bbb3_57110a81fc84_ctl00_ctl05_ctl12_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl02').style.visibility='hidden';

$('nobr:contains("Rejected")').closest('tr').hide();
}
else
{
//$('nobr:contains("Field2")').closest('tr').show();
}
});
</script>
```

its not working.

Comment: at which line error occurred ?

Comment: there was no error its just not hiding as needed

Comment: Does the alert ever trigger? You might try adding looking in the browser dev tool and seeing if your styles are being applied correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Using F12 to check the radio button elements, we will find the values of the radio buttons are ctl00, ctl01, ctl02.... Please use F12 check your exact radio button values.
[image]

Then use this script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

//In my “status” column, button values: Save-"ctl00" Submitted-"ctl01" Rejected-"ctl02" Approved-"ct103"

function hideOrShowOptions(){

                  var status = $("input[name$='ctl00$RadioButtons']:checked").val();

                  //alert(status);

                  if(status == "ctl00" || status == "ctl01"){

                                $(".ms-RadioText[title='Rejected']").closest("tr").css("display","none");

                                $(".ms-RadioText[title='Approved']").closest("tr").css("display","none");                               

                  } else {

                                $(".ms-RadioText[title='Rejected']").closest("tr").css("display","");

                                $(".ms-RadioText[title='Approved']").closest("tr").css("display","");          

                  }



}

$(document).ready( function() {

                hideOrShowOptions();

                $("input[name$='ctl00$RadioButtons']").change(function(){

                  hideOrShowOptions();

                });

});

</script>
```